# JavaScript Array.shift not working

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have been programming a system that is supposed to delete the first index of an array. Instead of changing an array from (i.e) "1,2,3,4,5" to "2,3,4,5" the console gives an error: "Uncaught TypeError: num.splice is not a function". I have heard that num.splice *is not* a function, it is an operation (or something) to delete the first indexed value of the array. I am confused that when I use an example code from [w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_shift), there is no outputted error in the console. I don't understand why this happens.

**(I have given the entire code just in case it has to do with syntax issues)**

```
function dCrypt() {
    var num = document.getElementById("demoin").value; // ex: a127
    var key = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
    var mod = 0;
    var out = 0;
    var prep = 0;
    var pre = 0;
    num.split("");
    mod = num[0];
    pre = key.indexOf(mod);
    num.splice(0,1);
    for (i=0;i <= pre;i++) {
        prep += 26;
    }
    out = Math.floor(num + pre);
    document.getElementById("demoout").innerHTML = out;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `num` is not an array.  It's a string.  If you want to call splice, you first have to convert it to an array.  You can do this with `Array.from(num)`.

Answer (score 6):

When you split 'num' you have to reassign it

```
num = num.split("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Referring to your link from w3schools:

> The splice() method adds/removes items **to/from an array**, and returns the removed item(s).

As you can see the var `num` is string(and not an array) and has the value of the element with id `demoin`.

Since you are trying to splice a string and not an array. The error shows up in the console.

**Solution:**

Either store the value of your `split` in an array(it could be `num` itself) and then `splice` that array.

```
num = num.split("");
...
num.splice(0,1);
```